# Нужен ли PRIMARY KEY в таблице с временными записями

Tags: mysql, sql

Существует таблица, где хранятся временные записи

| forein_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 345654 | 340 |
| 938930 | 560 |

В течении 10 секунд туда идет вставка новых записей, далее в течении 2-3 минут могут быть удалены некоторые записи, после все оставшиеся записи удаляются. Связь с другой таблице идет посредству forein_id. Нужен ли этой таблице еще одно поле с PRIMARY KEY и почему?

Comment: 1) Нет. 2) Нет функции, которую можно возложить на ПК. А уникально идентифицировать запись только для того, чтобы уникально идентифицировать - это разновидность [censored].